# Is that possible to force an application to be opened just by another application?

Tags: ios

I have 2 iOS applications. By clicking on a button from so called the "parent" app, the "child" app gets opened. Is there any way that I can force the "child" app just to be opened whenever the request comes from the "parent" app (just by clicking on the button)?

Comment: No. Any app installed by the user can be opened by the user. Don't make it two separate apps. Why would you consider making it two separate apps when the user can't use it without have the other app?

Comment: Right! sounds a bit stupid but the parent app is an ionic app. The child one is a native iOS app and all because the ionic does not have a very good support for AR related stuff.